# user enters name before quiz starts using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a quiz but would like to know how to start when making a user input to email.

Basically I would like the user to enter their name before they start my quiz and then once they have finished the quiz the results get sent to me by email using Javascript.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

You can't send email with plain JavaScript as far as I know, you will need to have a service, backend or a php file..

for example this php file:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

$errors = '';

if(empty($errors))
{
    $from_name = $_POST['name'];
    $from_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to_email = 'your@email.com';
    $to_email_cc = $from_email;

    $contact = "<p><strong>Name:</strong> $from_name</p>
            <p><strong>Email:</strong> $from_email</p>";
    $content = "<p>$message</p>";

    $email_subject = "Neue Nachricht von $from_name erhalten";
    $email_subject_cc = "Deine Nachricht wurde gesendet";

    $email_body = '<html><body>';
    $email_body .= "$contact $content";
    $email_body .= '</body></html>';

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $my_email\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_email";

    mail($to_email,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    mail($to_email_cc,$email_subject_cc,$email_body,$headers);

    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
    echo json_encode($response_array);
} else {
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    echo json_encode($response_array);
}
?>
```

and then you could do a post on that with for example angular, jquery or other.. 
something like this:

```
postEmail(newMail: Email): Observable<string>{
    let body = `name=${newMail.name}&email=${newMail.email}&message=${newMail.message}`;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body, options)
                    //.map(res =>  <string> res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

this is some old code from angular2 i wrote once and is not tested, but it should give you an idea of how to do it.